# How to handle List<Map<String, Object>> return type from query resolver in .graphqls

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, graphql

I have a graphql implementation, below is my .graphqls file

```
   schema { 
   query: Query

   } 

   type Product { 
    id: Int! 
    name: String! 
    description: String!
    productTypes: [ProductType]!
  } 

  type City { 
    id: Int! 
    name: String!
  }

  type ProductType { 
    id: Int! 
    type: String!
    product: Int
  }

  type Query {
    products: [Product]!
    cities: [City]!
    productTypes: [ProductType]!
  }
```

This is my query resolver code

```
   public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {


      @Autowired
      ProductRespository productRespository;

      @Autowired
      EntityManager em;

      @Autowired
      CityRepository cityRepository;

      @Autowired
      ProductTypeRepository productTypeRepository;



      public List<Map<String, Object>> products() {
           javax.persistence.Query q = em.createQuery("select new 
           map(p.name as productName, p.id as productId) from Product p");
           List<Map<String, Object>> list = q.getResultList();
           return list;


      }

     public Iterable<City> cities() {
         return cityRepository.findAll();
     }
}
```

when I am running the application I am getting below error

Type java.util.Map cannot be 
 mapped to a GraphQL type!  Since GraphQL-Java deals with erased types at 
 runtime, only non-parameterized classes can represent a GraphQL type.
 This allows for reverse-lookup by java class in interfaces and union 
 types

So how I can handle this kind of return type in Query Section of .graphqls

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In your `products()` method you only need to return a list of products not a list of map of string and products. You should change your return to match `List<Object>`.